# is it possible to test the network connection is via cellular data network in Iphone app

Tags: iphone, reachability

is it possible to test the network connection is via  cellular data network in Iphone app

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample to see if you are on wifi or wwan.  If it is not wifi it is cellular data.

See [Reachability sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942968/reachability-sample-code)

Comment: thank you very much Drawnonward for your response ,I want to get the data from url using cellular data network if wifi is also there. Could you please help for getting it .Thanks